# Manage two timestamps

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have two timestamps in one table.
1 - `timestamp01` - This will record timestamp when user creating new row in database 
2 - `timestamp02` - This should record timestamp when user update/ edit anything in the specific row.
My question is how do I setup `timestamp02` to record current timestamp when user did some changes to the specific row?

I am using MySQL as my database

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html. So you would have to mark that column as auto-updated to keep track of all updates to row

timestamp02 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

However, take note as the doc says

> One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

Comment: Could you please explain little bit more?

Comment: So basically, for the column to keep timestamp when column is updated, you need to create the column of type timestamp with default being CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on mark ON UPDATE as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, so your column will be updated on each update of the row. However, if you want to have 2 columns in table one just to keep default initial value and one to keep the auto-update time value, that is not possible according to the doc. However, I have not tried having two timestamp columns any time, so you can just check that